# Python how to check if the script has ended

Tags: python, command-line, error-handling

So I am creating a script that needs to be run 24/7 on a server machine. I have created try/excepts to catch if the script stops for any reason and send me an email.

However, there is nothing that will happen if the command line is closed. Therefore, there will be no notification if the command line closes for any reason while the script stops.

I'm not sure how to add code to be able to do that, but it is important because I need to know anytime the script has been stopped. At the moment I can only check if it is stopped in any way except closing the window.

Comment: You can use the function exit(n) where n=0 if it is successful or 1 if an error.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ how would I check if exit(0) is executed and handle it?

Comment: are you running you python via linux bash script or thru batch cmd in windows?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ I am running the script on command line in windows

Comment: what I did to my project is to create another python script (say: run.py) calling my main.py; Main.py will have an exception handling when it abruptly exits and an exit(0) if things went smoothly. this run.py is then executed by a windows scheduler using anaconda prompt (not windows cmd prompt). Also, I have a logging in main.py to capture error details when my main.py gets an error or not.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ What was the line to capture if the command line closes? That's what I am confused about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192969/discussion-between-anxmous-and-afsheen-taheri).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple answer that I hope will work for you using python's atexit module:

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    # do this stuff when the script exits
    return

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Keep in mind the exit handler function won't execute if there is some sort of fatal internal error or it was terminated at a low level, but for this most part this should work :)